# How can I copy a cell containing a document Hyperlink and put it into a table column on a new row

Tags: excel, vba, forms, hyperlink

I am new to Excel VBA so be patient with me.
I have a simple form that I want to create different document hyperlinks for a particular Organization.
What I am trying to do is add data to a table that contains:

- in column 1 the organization id
- in column 2 a brief description of the document
- in column 3 a Hyperlink to that document.

The user will enter the brief description and then click on a button to find the file.
The code then places the hyperlink into cell C1, it's this hyperlink I want in column 3 of a new row in the table row.
The form will contain a listbox which will show all entries in the table for the selected Organization, my idea is the user will then select an entry in the listbox which will then open the document.

My code so far:

```
Private Sub btnFindDocument_Click()

    Dim ActiveSheet As Worksheet

    Dim newRow As ListRow
    Dim lastRow As Integer
       
    Dim xPickedFile As Boolean
    Dim xPickFile As FileDialog
    Dim FullFileName As String
    Dim filename As String
    Dim fileNameNoExt As String
            
    Set ActiveSheet = Sheets("OrgDocument")
        
    ActiveSheet.Activate
    
    
    '// Opens dialog box to Pick File to Hyperlink
    Set xPickFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    '// Set the title and the xPickedFile to False to handle if the user cancels
    With xPickFile
        .Title = "Select file to hyperlink" 'Set title of the dialog box
        xPickedFile = False                 'Set to False
        xPickedFile = .Show                 'Open the file picker
        If xPickedFile Then                 'xPickedFile = True so continue with macro

            'Picked file as full file path and name
            FullFileName = .SelectedItems(1)

            'File name with extension
            filename = Right(FullFileName, Len(FullFileName) - InStrRev(FullFileName, "\"))

            'File name without extension
            fileNameNoExt = Left(filename, (InStr(filename, ".") - 1))

            'Hyperlink formula for active cell, change the friendly (display) name to either
            'the full file name, file name or file name and no extension
            'ActiveCell.Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" & FullFileName & """,""" & FileNameNoExt & """)"
            
            Range("C1").Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" & FullFileName & """,""" & fileNameNoExt & """)"
            
            Set newRow = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tblOrgDocument").ListRows.Add
            
            With newRow
                .Range(1) = "2"
                .Range(2) = txtDocumentDescription.Text
'***            .Range(3) =  THIS IS WHERE I AM STUCK I WANT COPY THE CONTENTS OF CELL "C1"
'***                         WHICH IS A HYPERLINK AND PUT THE HYPERLINK INTO THE 3rd COLUMN ON THIS ROW
'***                         SO THE USER CAN CLICK ON IT TO OPEN THE DOCUMENT
                
           End With
            
            txtDocumentDescription.Value = ""
        
        End If
    End With
              
End Sub
```

Comment: Firstly, you have to define `newRow` (by incrementing a variable). Then you can copy the formula: `.Range(3).Formula = Range("C1").Formula`. And finally, no need to keep all the code inside `With xPickFile ... End With`. `End With` should come after the `FullFileName` definition (`FullFileName = .SelectedItems(1)`). After that, your code does not need any of the `xPickFile` properties.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and it placed the hyperlink formula in the cell as expected, but when I add another document hyperlink, it places the latest formula in Range("C1") in ALL cells in column 3 overwriting the origin hyperlink.

Comment: This only proves that you did not follow my **first** suggestion. The way you defined `newRow` looks to be inappropriate. How did you do that? There are many ways. You could use your first "cell as expected" as reference (`rngRef`), use `rngRef.Offset(i)` and increment `i` for each new necessary hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

With the help from FaneDuru and further investigation I found a solution that works for me.
I replaced the following code :`
Set newRow = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tblOrgDocument").ListRows.Add

```
        With newRow
            .Range(1) = "2"
            .Range(2) = txtDocumentDescription.Text
```

'***            .Range(3) =  THIS IS WHERE I AM STUCK I WANT COPY THE CONTENTS OF CELL "C1"
'***                         WHICH IS A HYPERLINK AND PUT THE HYPERLINK INTO THE 3rd COLUMN ON THIS ROW
'***                         SO THE USER CAN CLICK ON IT TO OPEN THE DOCUMENT

```
       End`
```

With:

```
        lastRow = (ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) + 1
        
        Cells(lastRow, 1).Value = "1"
        Cells(lastRow, 2).Value = txtDocumentDescription.Text
        Cells(lastRow, 3).Formula = Range("C1").Formula
```